# Beanstalkd custom task delay for 2nd and 3rd retry

Tags: php, queue, beanstalkd

I use Beanstalkd (with - https://github.com/udokmeci/yii2-beanstalk) for queues. But I need to set custom delay for next retry,

1st - with no delay
2nd - in a hour
3th - in 24 hrs

Is it possible to implement this with Beanstalkd?

```
public function actionCron($job)
{
    $sentData = $job->getData();
    try {

        // I need to setup custom delay there
        // 1 hour after 1st retry
        // 24 hrs after 2nd retry

        return self::DELAY;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //If there is anything to do.
        fwrite(STDERR, Console::ansiFormat($e . "\n", [Console::FG_RED]));

        // you can also bury jobs to examine later
        return self::BURY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible - by asking the Beanstalkd server for stats about the job.

From the Beanstalk [protocol.txt](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/96e875678bb262343a0caa461b8927a2d2260f6f/doc/protocol.txt) file:

```
stats-job <id>\r\n
```

The data returned includes the number of times the job has previously been reserved, released, and from which tube-name etc. You can use whatever data is most appropriate to re-queue it as required.

Since you can't change the data to delay it, only create a new job, an option is to put it into a new queue for a 2nd or 3rd attempt, with suitable initial delay, and then if the job has come from a retry-queue (after the 1st, or 2nd attempt), alter the initial delay before it is run again.

Since you can attempt to get a job from multiple queues, you'll just have your code watch the main queue, and *also* the 2nd/3rd-attempt tubes and see what they are given, processing as appropriate.